# How to get Hangouts Chrome app tray-icon in Unity? (without opening Chrome browser)

Tags: unity, google-chrome, webapps

Is there anyway I can get the Hangouts Chrome App window in Ubuntu 13.04 if I close the Chrome Browser?

`ps -eaf| grep chrome`

This gives me that there are few instance of Chrome is running and indicating the
**"Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"** option is working fine here.

In Windows 7, System Tray will have a Hangout icon to get the hangout window, without even opening the Chrome Browser.

Is there a way to get this in Ubuntu?

Comment: The tray icons are actually included with the linux version, but they are not appindicators and hence hidden by unity. I'm curious for a solution as well (one that does not involve 'hacking' unity to re-add the tray whitelist functionality).

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 removed the ability to whitelist systray apps (http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/unity-notification-area-systray.html). I am also looking for a solution to your question.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a huge issue for me, so to be fair, I haven't tried this fix yet.  However it seems like it should work.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:timekiller/unity-systrayfix
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That should give you the ability to whitelist apps again for the unity notification area.  Then just add everything to the whitelist like so:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

You'll probably have to kill or your chrome processes and restart to see the changes.

Found this info at 
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html

Comment: The link you give is too generic, please [edit] it so it points to the actual article you read.

Comment: @edwin all set.  link updated.

Answer (score 2):

Telling from [this issue on the Chromium tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=258651), it appears that work is being done to support Unity's appindicators, at least as of a month ago.

So hopefully a real solution to this isn't too far off, but for now the closest thing to a solution using a modified version of Unity that adds the whitelist back, like [Stephano](https://askubuntu.com/a/336027/148888) suggested.